# Objects changed rotation jumps to it's original Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made input joysticks for mobile game. One that moves the player and other one that changes it's rotation. Both are working fine but only problem is that when I change players rotation and release that joystick it jumps to it's original rotation. Here's my script:

```
public GameObject player;
private PlayerInput playerInput;

void Update()
{
    Vector2 input = playerInput.actions["Move"].ReadValue<Vector2>();
    Vector3 move = new Vector3(input.x, input.y, 0);
    player.transform.position += move * speed * Time.deltaTime;

    Vector2 look = playerInput.actions["Look"].ReadValue<Vector2>();
    player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, look);
}
```

Comment: Please put a picture of the problem and explain how you want it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically solve this by ignoring rotation values of small magnitude and maintaining the last frame's orientation in said case. You might have to tune the threshold below to filter out the correct values.

```cs
public GameObject player;
private PlayerInput playerInput;
private Vector2 look;

void Update()
{
    Vector2 input = playerInput.actions["Move"].ReadValue<Vector2>();
    Vector3 move = new Vector3(input.x, input.y, 0);
    player.transform.position += move * speed * Time.deltaTime;

    var inputLook = playerInput.actions["Look"].ReadValue<Vector2>();
    look = inputLook.magnitude > 0.1f ? inputLook : look;
    player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, look);
}
```